# how to get url last part after slash as get value in php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

My url is look like: `http://localhost/event_manage?slug=hello` and last value as like `hello`
So that page is in `index.php` when i go `http://localhost/event_manage/hello` and shows error because there is no folder as named `hello`.
But i want this `hello` is like GET value When I go `http://localhost/event_manage/hello`

I tried in `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?slug=$1
```

But it still shows error and couldn't pass the value!

Comment: Do you have any other directives in your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: No i need just only when enter `http://localhost/event_manage/hello` it will collect the last value as get value and that page is index.php (so my url is without index.php) but others page like ` http://localhost/event_manage/dashboard.php` is working fine..

Comment: So, `/event_manage` is a physical subdirectory? Where are your `.htaccess` and `index.php` files located? Although if `/event_manage` is a physical subdirectory then the URL is `/event_manage/?slug=hello` (with a trailing slash).

Comment: /event_manage is its in localhost just a directory all the files are in this directory

Comment: "it still shows error" - what do you mean by this? Are you getting a 404 and `index.php` is not being called at all?

Comment: when i go `http://localhost/event_manage?slug=hello` its working fine but error is `http://localhost/event_manage/hello` this page shows 404 because i couldn't wrote any htaccess yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?slug=$1
> ```
>
> but error is `http://localhost/event_manage/hello`

The above rule assumes your URL ends in a trailing slash, but your example does not, so it will fail to match and result in a 404 (because it's not rewriting the request to `index.php`).

It should be:

```
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)$ index.php?slug=$1 [L]
```

`\w` (word characters) is just a shorthand character class, the same as `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`.

You need the `L` flag if you add any more directives.

This assumes `.htaccess` and `index.php` are located inside the `/event_manage` subdirectory.

---

*Aside:*

> ```
> http://localhost/event_manage?slug=hello
> ```

Since `/event_manage` is a physical directory, this URL should be `http://localhost/event_manage/?slug=hello` (with a trailing slash after the directory name). If you omit the trailing slash then mod_dir will append the trailing slash with a 301 redirect.

Comment: so what is my answer? this one: `RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)$ index.php?slug=$1 [L]`
if i go `http://localhost/event_manage/hello` now it redirect to `http://localhost/hello` -_-

Comment: @shawn Yes, as I've stated in my answer. Basically, I've just removed the trailing slash from the regex since your example URL does not include a trailing slash.

Comment: "now it redirect to `http://localhost/hello`" - there are no redirects in this code, so that would seem to be impossible with the directive as written. Make sure you have cleared your browser cache.

Comment: @shawn From what you have written, it would seem to be a simple fix. The one-line of code in my answer replaces the one-line of code in your question. Your regex matched a trailing slash on the URL-path, but your example URL did not have a trailing slash, so the two do not match and the rule does nothing.

Comment: okay let me check this.. it works now after clearing cache

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?slug=$1
```

Comment: This unexplained (basically a repost MrWhite's answer except you removed the trailing slash) doesn't really add anything of value to the page.

Comment: @mickmackusa that trailing slash was breaking for me, hence reposted.